# Why does my project require multiple npmrc registries when the artifact already includes them as upstream sources?

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have two mono repositories that use Node/NPM/Lerna to manager and distribute multiple packages.

**Project X** includes `.npmrc` file with a single registry. This registry is for a private Azure Feed that includes three upstream sources. **Named** ( A, B, C )

1. **A** - Public NPMJS
2. **B** - Private Package
3. **C** - Private Package

**Project Y** *requires* `.npmrc` file with two namespaced registries.

1. The first is the same that **Project X** uses.
2. The second **seems** to be required and @register's the Azure Feed for **B**.

My question is if my `.npmrc` file is registering a package that contains three upstream feeds, why do I additionally have to register one of these upstream feeds in my `.npmrc` file (**B**)?

It was my understanding from documentation that Upstream Feeds are an alternative approach to registering multiple namespaced packages in your `.npmrc` file.

I'm clearly missing something. Please assist. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that Project X is using the set-up that we recommend, which is a single Azure Artifacts feed in your `.npmrc`'s `registry=` line that upstreams to any other feeds you need.

However, Project Y may have chosen to use [scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/scopes?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav%2Cwindows) to instead only use limited packages from Azure Artifacts while pulling most packages directly from npmjs.com. We generally don't recommend this, but it's a valid way to work. Note that in this configuration, Project Y does not get to take advantage of the benefits of upstream sources (like a saved copy of anything you use from npmjs.com, in case it's later deleted).

If you want to migrate to the recommended configuration, try ensuring that Project Y's `.npmrc` has a single `registry=` line:

`registry=https://dev.azure.com/.../ProjectXFeedWithUpstreams/...`

and see if it still builds (delete or rename `node_modules` when you run `npm install`).

Comment: Alex Mullans - The only reason we configured Project Y in this manner was because Project X was returning 403 errors.  Perhaps this is an Azure DevOps bug.

Comment: What if we are publishing **B** also?  Do we have to use the explicit registry for **B** or should Project X still authenticate that request.  Assuming the token includes proper publishing permissions?

Comment: Did you set up authentication in your user-level `.npmrc`, and do you have permissions to the feed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc 
403 generally indicates that you don't have permissions.
If you are publishing B, that will work just fine as long as you have credentials set up (using the link earlier in this comment) and your project-level `.npmrc` has `registry=<your-registry>`.

Comment: Yes, the registry is inside the user-level `.npmrc` file and we have permissions because it was working great on Project X.  It wasn't until we switched to Project Y that we started getting the 403 error.  Project Y is the source repository that is also used to publish our private packages (**B**).  For some reason, we had add itself to the `.npmrc` file in order to get past the 403 error.

Comment: Ah, I see what I missed. If Project Y has only namespaced registries in the .npmrc (`@<scope>:registry=...`), npm will only try to retrieve packages that match that particular scope from the registry. npm also does credential matching based on the `@<scope>:registry` string, so you may need the same credential multiple times in your user .npmrc: once with `registry=` and once per `@<scope>:registry=`. However, if you change Y to only have `registry=` (no scope), do you still have the 403 error?

Comment: Yes.  This was my original problem.  Project X was using Upstream Feed feature so that I only need the one registry.  This worked fine on that project. But, when another contributor made changes on package then to publish that package they required `@<scope>:registry`.  Which my understanding should not be required.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what's going on then, sorry.

Comment: At this point I think it might be a bug.  I'll file a ticket issue on Azure DevOps team and follow up here when that is closed.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What would be the recommended approach for accessing 3 private feeds.  Let's say this is all open source and each feed is by a different organization.  1 feed has upstream feeds to 2 other private feeds that are specific to the same organization.  The other two feeds may or may not use upstream feed.  I would then be required to use @scoping correct?  So my question now comes down how upstream feeds can be a recommended approach?  Feels like there would be a recommended approach for a single private feed and then another for multiple private feeds.  Thinking the documentation could be expanded